# "Adj Close" data could be different in different data range?

Tags: market-data

I use `python DataReader` for getting past stock data.

I heard that `Adj Close` data could be different each other if data range is different between datas. This is because (as I know of) `Close` data is adjusted based on the LAST DATE of period.

For example,

> APPL1_data : 2010-01-01 ~ 2016-01-01 adj close data
>
> APPL2_data : 2014-01-01 ~ 2016-01-01 adj close data

But as I compare these datas by myself, both have same `Adj close` datas even though ex-dividend, stock split have happend during this period.

Did I miss something?

Comment: In my experience (your system may be different) if I download APPL1_data and APPL2_data on the same day they will be the same. I I download one of them on 2016-01-02 morning and the other on 2016-02-15 (today) they could be different. The data system will have updated its Adjustment in the meantime.

Comment: ...they will have updated the adjustment _if_ there were ex-div or stk split between 2016-01-02 and 2016-02-15.

Comment: @noob2 oh..Now I understand..... I'd like to store 10 years  `Adj close` data of 100 stocks in my Database. In this case, do I have to update `Adj close` of all dataset everyday? It would be very hard work...T _ T